# Disable input in a form when another input is filled in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to disable all input type in a form when one of them is checked or filled with a value.

When one of the checkbox is checked will disable the other two fields, same for the input text.

Here some code try:

HTML

```
<form action="">
   <input type="text" id="name"/>
   <input type="checkbox" id="days" name="days" />
   <input type="checkbox" id="months" name="months" />
</form>
```

JS

```
 function disableInput(e) {
    if(e.target.value !== 0) {
       document.getElementById("days").disabled = true;
       document.getElementById("months").disabled = true;
     }else {
       document.getElementById("days").disabled = false;
       document.getElementById("months").disabled = false;
            }
        }

const name = document.querySelector('#name');
name.addEventListener('input', disableInput);
```

How can I manage this in vanilla JS?

Answer (score 1):

The `input` event will bubble up. So listen for that event on the `<form>` element to capture all activity on the inputs.

When the event is triggered, check the type of event and if either the `value` is empty or the `checked` property equals `true`, depending on the `type` value.

Then loop over all the inputs in the form. All your inputs can be found in the [`elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) property on the form. In the loop disable all the inputs except the one you're currently using.

Restore all the inputs when the aforementioned condition is not met.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

function disableInputs(exception) {
  for (const input of form.elements) {
    if (input !== exception) {
      input.disabled = true;
    }
  }
}

function enableInputs() {
  for (const input of form.elements) {
    input.disabled = false;
  }
}

form.addEventListener('input', event => {
  const { target } = event;

  if (
    (target.type === 'text' && target.value !== '') ||
    (target.type === 'checkbox' && target.checked === true)
  ) {
    disableInputs(target);
  } else {
    enableInputs();
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="days" name="days" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="months" name="months" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function lockOut(e) {
  this.querySelectorAll("input:not(#" + e.srcElement.id + ")").forEach(function(elem) {
    if (e.srcElement.type !== "text") elem.disabled = !elem.disabled;
    else if (e.srcElement.value.length > 0) elem.disabled = true;
    else elem.disabled = false;
  });
}

document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("input", lockOut);
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="days" name="days" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="months" name="months" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my simple solution:

```js
const allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.radio-input');

allInputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  
    let value;
    
    switch(e.target.type) {
      case 'checkbox':
        value = e.target.checked;
        break;
      case 'text':
        value = e.target.value;
        break;
    }
    
    const needDisable = !(value === '' || value === false);
    
    allInputs.forEach((input) => {
      if (input === e.target) {
        input.disabled = false;
        return;
      }
      
      input.disabled = needDisable;
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="">
   <input type="text" class="radio-input" id="name"/>
   <input type="checkbox" class="radio-input" id="days" name="days" />
   <input type="checkbox" class="radio-input" id="months" name="months" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>`enter code here`
<style>
    .error{
        color: red;
    }
</style>
<body>

<form id="registrationForm" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" onblur="disableField(this)" oninput="checkSubmitButton()">
    <button type="button" onclick="toggleInput('name')">edit</button>
    <span class="error" id="nameError"></span>
    <br><br>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" onblur="disableField(this)" oninput="checkSubmitButton()">
    <button type="button" onclick="toggleInput('email')">edit</button>
    <span class="error" id="emailError"></span>
    <br><br>

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" onblur="disableField(this)" oninput="checkSubmitButton()">
    <button type="button" onclick="toggleInput('password')">edit</button>
    <span class="error" id="passwordError"></span>
    <br><br>

    <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" onblur="disableField(this)" oninput="checkSubmitButton()">
    <button type="button" onclick="toggleInput('confirmPassword')">edit</button>
    <span class="error" id="confirmPasswordError"></span>
    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" disabled></input>
</form>

<script>
const form = document.getElementById("registrationForm");
function disableField(inputField) {
    if (inputField.value.trim() !== '') {
        inputField.disabled = true;
    }
}

function toggleInput(inputId) {
    const inputField = document.getElementById(inputId);
    inputField.disabled = !inputField.disabled;
    checkSubmitButton();
}

function checkSubmitButton() {
    const name = document.getElementById("name").value.trim();
    const email = document.getElementById("email").value.trim();
    const password = document.getElementById("password").value.trim();
    const confirmPassword = document.getElementById("confirmPassword").value.trim();
    const submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");
    const nameError = document.getElementById("nameError");
    const emailError = document.getElementById("emailError");
    const passwordError = document.getElementById("passwordError");
    const confirmPasswordError = document.getElementById("confirmPasswordError");
    const emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;

    nameError.textContent = "";
    emailError.textContent = "";
    passwordError.textContent = "";
    confirmPasswordError.textContent = "";

    let isValid = true;

    if (name === "") {
        nameError.textContent = "Name is required";
        isValid = false;
    }

    if (email === "") {
        emailError.textContent = "Email is required";
        isValid = false;
    } else if (!emailPattern.test(email)) {
        emailError.textContent = "Invalid email format";
        isValid = false;
    }

    if (password === "") {
        passwordError.textContent = "Password is required";
        isValid = false;
    } else if (password.length < 6) {
        passwordError.textContent = "Password must be at least 6 characters long";
        isValid = false;
    }

    if (confirmPassword === "") {
        confirmPasswordError.textContent = "Please confirm your password";
        isValid = false;
    } else if (confirmPassword !== password) {
        confirmPasswordError.textContent = "Passwords do not match";
        isValid = false;
    }

    if (isValid) {
        submitButton.disabled = false;
    } else {
        submitButton.disabled = true;
    }



form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
            // event();
            if (isValid) {
                // Retrieve existing user data from local storage or initialize an empty array
                const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData')) || [];
                // console.log(userData);

                // Add the new user data
                userData.push({ name, email, password });
                
                // Save the updated user data back to local storage
                localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userData));

                // console.log(userData);
                form.reset(); // Clear the form after submission
                // alert('Form Succesfully Submitted');
                // window.location.href="/preet/tictacgame.html"
            }
        
});
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      const input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
      const input2 = document.getElementById('input2');

      input1.addEventListener('input', () => {
        if (input1.value !== '') {
          input2.disabled = true;
        } else {
          input2.disabled = false;
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
 <form>
    <label for="input1">Input 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="input1"><br><br>
    
    <label for="input2">Input 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="input2">
  </form>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).